# Excel columns are stretched on one PC only

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of similar spreadsheets where the columns are aligned so that the whole sheet exactly fits one 1920 x 1080 screen when maximized. There is a row of identical evenly-spaced buttons at the top.

Suddenly (I think it was after the W10 Anniversary Update), when I open one of these sheets, the column widths are all different. ie a column that is 4.14 on all the other machines shows as 4.25 on mine. This also stretches the buttons randomly.

The really weird thing is that when I save the sheet and I open the spreadsheets on any other machine, the widths are back to normal (4.14).

I have tried uninstalling Office, restarting and re-installing and the problem persists. Please help.

Update: Using Office365 E3 (2016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the computer affected was merely the first one in the company to get the Anniversary Update. Once i noticed it happening to more and more machines, I adjusted the sheet to suit the new normal.

So the answer is, the W10 Anniversary Update does break Excel column widths and you need to change these as your computers update.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say this is related to the size of text on Windows in general

From [this guide](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20text%20size%20windows%2010):

1. Right-click on desktop and select Display settings.
2. Use the slider to change the size of text, app, and other items to 100%. It might be set to 150% by default.
3. Tap or click the Apply button. A window pops up to let you know that signing out of Windows and signing back in is recommended.

Good luck!